# Python: Given a number return tuple from 0, a number given

Tags: python

Hi I would like to knoq how I can achieve this in python.

given: num=4

expect: (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)  (in tuple)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here's a hint - create a range up to your number + 1 and then use `itertools.product` to get a Cartesian product of the two copies of that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested loops:

```
>>> num = 4
>>> for i in range(num):
...     for j in range(i+1, num+1):
...         print((i, j))
...
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Using `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(*itertools.combinations(range(num+1), 2), sep="\n")
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```